# Cloud Functions for Firebase getting value of key

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to get the value from author, but it says that it's undefined.

How do I get the value from a specific child from firebase in javascript in Cloud Functions for Firebase, the follwing code should work(?):

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');                                          

const admin = require('firebase-admin');                                                  

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);                                         

exports.sendPushForHelp =                                                                 
functions.database.ref('/schools/Vittra/alarms/active/{id}').onCreate(event => {      
    const id = event.params.id;                                                       
    var eventSnapshot = event.data.val();                                             
    var ref = admin.database().ref("/schools/Vittra/alarms/{eventSnapshot}/authorId");
    ref.once('value').then(function(snapshot) {                                       
        var author = snapshot.val();                                                  
    });                                                                               






    const payLoad = {                                                                 
        notification: {                                                               
            title: String(eventSnapshot),                                             
            body: String(author),                                                     
            badge: '1',                                                               
            sound: 'Intruder.mp3'                                                     
        }                                                                             
    };                                                                                

return admin.database().ref('fcmToken').once('value').then(allToken => {                  
        if (allToken.val()) {                                                             
     const token = Object.keys(allToken.val());                                            
     return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token, payLoad).then(response => 
{              

           });                                                                           

        };                                                                                
    });                                                                                   

});
```

Comment: If you add a image of your database, and show me exactly what you want, I can take a look

Answer (score 1):

You're ignoring the promise returned from this query:

```
ref.once('value').then(function(snapshot) {                                       
    var author = snapshot.val();                                                  
});
```

Before you can use the value of `author`, you need to but the code that depends on `author` *inside* the function that responds to that promise, more like this:

```
var author;

return ref.once('value').then(function(snapshot) {                                       
    author = snapshot.val();
    return admin.database().ref('fcmToken').once('value')
}).then(function(snapshot) {
    if (allToken.val()) {                                                             
        const token = Object.keys(allToken.val());                                            
        const payLoad = ...
        return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token, payLoad)
    }
}).then(function(response) {
    // ...continue
})
```

The bottom line is that you need to learn how to chain your promises correctly.

Comment: Thank you for the help I am new to javascript (only used to swift). When I did it the way you suggested I get the error that payload is not defined.

Comment: I edited the code slightly to define payload just before it's needed.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared **author** inside the firebase callback.

```
    var eventSnapshot = event.data.val();                                             
    var ref = admin.database().ref("/schools/Vittra/alarms/{eventSnapshot}/authorId");
    ref.once('value').then(function(snapshot) {                                       
        var author = snapshot.val();  // Here is the problem                                                
    });
```

And you are using it here as :

```
const payLoad = {                                                                 
        notification: {                                                               
            title: String(eventSnapshot),                                             
            body: String(author), // <------                                                    
            badge: '1',                                                               
            sound: 'Intruder.mp3'                                                     
        }                                                                             
    };
```

define author outside like eventSnapshot , then you can use it further.

Use:

```
        var eventSnapshot = event.data.val();  
        var author = '';           
        var ref = admin.database().ref("/schools/Vittra/alarms/{eventSnapshot}/authorId");
        ref.once('value').then(function(snapshot) {                                       
            author = snapshot.val();                                                
        });
```